# using multiple sets of radio buttons, how can I unhide and hide images

Tags: javascript, html

Images //hide and show images with buttons

images are shown based on radio button/checkbox selected

```
<img id="storage_drawer" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/storage_drawer.png" />
<img id="cash_drawer" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/cash_drawer.png" />
```

Form       two sets of radio buttons// changed into checkboxes by javascript function

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cashdrawer" name="type" value="cashDrawer" class="unique" >
<input type="checkbox" id="cashStorage" name="type" value="storageDrawer" class="unique">
               //second set of radio buttons
<input type="checkbox" id="single" name="type2" value="singleLine" class="unique" >
<input type="checkbox" id="multi" name="type2" value="multiLine" class="unique" >
</form>
```

Start of script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        to make make checkboxes have the functionality of radio buttons
        var $inputs = $(".unique");

            $inputs.change(function(){
                $inputs.not(this).prop('checked');
            });
            return false;

        radio buttons -- first set of radio buttons
        $("input[name$=type]").click(function(){

            var value = $(this).val();
            //Cash Drawers
            if(value == 'cashDrawer') {
                $("#cash_drawer").show();
                $("#storage_drawer").hide();
            }
            else if( value == 'storageDrawer') {
                $("#storage_drawer").show();
                $("#cash_drawer").hide();
            }
        })
        $("#cash_drawer").hide();
        $("#storage_drawer").hide();


      second set of radio buttons

        $("input[name$=type2]").click(function(){

            var value = $(this).val();
            //Barcode Scanners
            if(value = 'singleLine') {
                $("#sinlgeBarcode").show();
                $("#multiBarcode").hide();
            }
            else if(value == 'multiLine') {
                $("#multiBarcode").show();
                $("#sinlgeBarcode").hide();
            }
        })
        $("#sinlgeBarcode").hide();
        $("#multiBarcode").hide();  
    });


    });
```

end of script

Comment: Can you put the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your radio boxes have the same name attribute they will behave as radio buttons i.e only one selection can be active in the group, but if each button have their own name they can all be selected.

So if u have a collection of radios like this:

```
<form>
   <input type="radio" name="1">
   <input type="radio" name="2">
   <input type="radio" name="3">
 </form>
```

U can get them to behave like check boxes with a lil javascript:

```
// This will allow the radio boxes to toggle on of.
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){ 
    $(this).attr("checked",  !$(this).attr("checked"));
});
```

Edit:

I did a js fiddler with a working example, maybe it will give some answers.

http://jsfiddle.net/uPp82/1/

Comment: It's not the checked part I'm having an issue with, it's getting the images to display on onclick... the first set displays but the second set doesn't

Comment: Okay, but what is the problem.. do the click handler for the second group fire?
Do the image selectors return the expected dom objects?

Comment: that would be the idea, I have tried solution before, I couldn't get it to work for some odd reason. Does it matter if the "show() or "hide() function is in a specific order?   if you use the checkbox behaviour it doesn't hide the images anymore.... that's my main issue currently.

Comment: When adding the "checkbox functionality" to the radio buttons, it also  removes the removes the hide and show functionality. you would have to used sometthing like:                                                           function toggleVisibility(id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);

        if (el.style.visibility == "visible") {
            el.style.visibility = "hidden";
        } else {
            el.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }

Comment: To get the checkbox behavior to work im my example u need to give each radio a uniqe name.
http://jsfiddle.net/uPp82/4/

If this is not what u want, I'm afraid i don't understand what it is u are looking for.

Comment: If u want the images do disappear again if u unchecked the buttons u can do like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/uPp82/5/